# Tomcat Servlet: - The requested resource is not available

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am new to writing a Java Servlet, and am struggling to get a simple servlet to work properly.

The Servlet Test1.java class is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


@WebServlet("/Test1")
public class Test1 extends HttpServlet {


  public Test1() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("Hello World");
  }
    }
```

The problem is when trying to run this simple servlet the servers shows an error which is :

message :  /Projet1/Test

HTTP 404 : the requested resource is not available

Projet1 is the name of the project

for web.xml i"ve removed the declaration of this servelt as i saw in many question , which says that we cant not use the annotation in the servelt and in web.xml at the same time , anyway this is web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
  version="3.0">
  <display-name>Projet1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
```

for the structure and the results : [Structure du projet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKXzP.png)

the result : [the result after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuZFx.png)

I am running Tomcat v7.0, and have already read similar questions, with responses referring to changing the invoker servlet-mapping section in web.xml , 
i've tried so many solutions pas no changes ! Help please .

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, and to describe the problem you're facing (inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs).

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you , i've edited the question again .

Comment: How do you assemble and deploy your project into Tomcat?

Comment: first i have created the projet named Projet1 , also i've created the servlet using new Servelt  , directly in src  , after this , i clicked on the servlet , right click run as : Run on server  .

Comment: Well, start by putting your class into a package. Don't, ever, use the default package. Then, if you're doing all this inside Eclipse, tag your question with eclipse, and post the structure of your project.

Comment: @JBNizet i've did what you told me to do , but always the same error  , i'v edited the question again